# You not given to or Something not given to

Tags: grammar

Is this correct construction to say "*You are not given to fly (any verb or noun)"*? Or is it only "*Flying is not given to you*"?
As having ability of something.

Answer (score 1):

If you are *given to* something, you have a habit of doing it.

> He was given to sitting up reading until midnight.

You can't use it to mean 'have the ability to do something'.

Comment: And second example is correct, right, meaning ability?

Comment: No, neither version is idiomatic. We sometimes say that someone has 'the gift of' or 'a gift for' doing something when they have an unusual talent or ability, but we don't use 'X is given to you'.